# How to initialize log4j2 after Spring bean creation?

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I want to get some log4j2 properties from my configuration bean but problem is Spring initializes this beans after log4j2 starts. Is there any way to initialize this bean before log4j2 provider?

```
<NoSql name="elasticsearchTimeAppender">
        //I will set below values from Spring conf. bean
        <Mongo cluster="" host="" port="" index="" type="" flushInterval=""/>
</NoSql>
```

Here is my provider;

```
@Plugin(name = "Mongo", category = "Core", printObject = true)
public class MongoProvider implements NoSqlProvider<MongoConnection> {
    ....
    host = MyConfiguration.DatabaseName; //I am getting null value here because Spring initializes after provider completed.
}
```

Here is my configuration bean;

```
@Component
public class MyConfiguration {

  public static String DatabaseName;

  @PostConstruct
  private void setStaticFields() {
    MyConfiguration.DatabaseName= databaseName;
  }

  @Value("${mydbconf.name}")
  private String databaseName;



  public String getDatabaseName() {
    return DatabaseName;
  }

  public void setDatabaseName(String DatabaseName) {
    MyConfiguration.DatabaseName = DatabaseName;
  }


}
```

Comment: Did you finally resolve the problem?